# How can I make nav-tabs stacked at window resizing in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my code I have `nav-tabs` and `on the right` I have a `search box`. Now while resizing I want everything to come one below the other at particular width. How can this be achieved only through `CSS or jquery` if possible. Other solutions are also very much welcome.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default" style="background-color: #666666; border-bottom: 1px solid white;">
<div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-3">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;"></span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="demo">         
          <li class="nav_zero" id="nav0"><a href="#home" style="color: #FFFFFF;" data-toggle="tab" id="anc1"><i class="fa fa-home fa-1x"></i> Home</a></li>  
          <li class="nav_zero" id="nav1"><a href="#profile" style="color: #FFFFFF;" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li> 
          <li class="nav_zero" id="nav2"><a href="#something1" style="color: #FFFFFF;" data-toggle="tab">Something1</a></li> 
          <li class="nav_zero" id="nav3"><a href="#something2" style="color: #FFFFFF;" data-toggle="tab">Something2</a></li> 
          <li class="nav_zero" id="nav4"><a href="#" style="color: #FFFFFF;" data-toggle="tab">Messages<span class="badge" style="background-color: red;">1</span></a></li>
          <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li>
            <form class="navbar-form" role="search" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label class="control-label sr-only" for="inputSuccess4">Input with success</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="inputSuccess4">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>

      </form>
          </li>
          </ul>         
        </ul> 
      </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
I added the following code:

```
@media (max-width: 840px) {
.pull-right {
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left !important;
}
.nav-tabs > li {
  float: none;
}
.nav-tabs > li + li {
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 0;
}
}
```

This got me what i wanted but is it a good practice to change the meaning completely?

**EDIT**

```
.pull-right-custom {

  float: right !important;
}

@media (max-width: 840px) {
.pull-right-custom {
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left !important;
}
```

How about this one. I guess this is completely fine now.

Comment: Use media query to target the width you want... and do css for the expected behavior. after that if you face any issue come with your code... we glad to help

Comment: can i add class with css?

Comment: Bootstrap having its native stacking of menu if you don't want this go with your own media query and add a class in that.

Comment: @media (max-width: 840px) {
.pull-right {
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left !important;
}
.nav-tabs > li {
  float: none;
}
.nav-tabs > li + li {
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 0;
}
}

Comment: the above code actually got me what i  wanted but is it a good practice, changing completely the meaning of .pull-right class. I am okay with it as it serves my purpose though

Comment: No, don't override the native code add your own class and do your styling. because upto 840px if any other element use .pull-right may break.

Comment: totally agree with this point.

Comment: Check out the second edit and let me know if that is fine implementation